# Links in SVG for mobile

Tags: svg

So I created with Illustrator a SVG with links, and those link in DESKTOP are working. But when I try to click on them, in MOBILE, nothing happens.

Any idea?

Here you can see it in action: tinyurl.com/y4p66s8f

Links are defined like this:

```
`<a xlink:href="mailto:benefits@xxx.com" target="_blank">
            <rect x="38" y="615" style="opacity:0;fill:#FFFFFF;" width="219" height="47"/>
        </a>`
```

I also tried defining data-navigate="mailto:benefits@xxx.com" but still not working.

Any suggestion! Really appreciate it.